# I have no simulate controls in construct classic

Tags: construct-2

I want to make other jump button in Construct Classic. But, as many people saying i need to use "simualte controls" action. But i can't find it. I tried to find it on many forums, googles, and nothing. I just can't

Comment: Have you added platform behavior to your object?

Comment: @Cypert yes i did

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like this:
[image]

In this case my player has this properties, but the only important one is that it has platform behaviour:
[image]

To make the new jump first you need to create an event when you press the new key and then click "Add action", then select the object with platform behaviour (in my case "player") then
[image]